# Site receives high amount of random requests

Tags: ddos

[Question moved from stackoverflow]

Since about two weeks, a site is receiving an increased amount of requests for nonexisting pages.

The calls are for existing pages but with a prefix of 5 random characters:

[image]

I was alerted to the situation by email from Google Webmaster console. Right now the attack has reached about 4000 hits/day, all resulting in error 404. The amount of hits is gradually increasing.

The site is part of an older site with mostly personal data, like photos. Long time ago I wrote a guide to the installation of Ubuntu. This part of the site is the one being attacked. I have a pretty neutral opinion on Linux distributions and have never  been part of any "flamewar". I never speak  badly about other distributions.

I also write about political matters, anonymously (I hope), on other sites. I write in a  neutral tone, but political matters can sometimes be sensitive.

My sites are hosted on GoDaddy.

Is this a form of DDoS attack? I don't think someone is trying to unlock directories with secret names? But 4000 requests/day are not enough to bring a site down.

The site is still accessible.

What can I do about it?

Comment: This is not a personal or targetted attack. Have you changed IPs recently? Any other server changes?

Comment: @schroeder No changes by me or GoDaddy as I am aware of. Why is this attack not targeted? One wild guess of mine was that someone had managed to identify me behind my political writings on other sites and is making this attack to my personal home page just to show "We know who you are."

Comment: No - this is pretty standard bot activity

Comment: are the IPs all over the place or from a narrow set of IPS?

Comment: @schroeder My problem is that I am traveling, only using phone. I will try to find logs from programs I made long ago. - I will supply attacker IP data as soon as possible. Why would bots hit a site for nonexistent pages, 4000 hits/24h?

Comment: Can you get the bot user agent? It can sometimes be a clue towards what is going on

Comment: @jrtapsell Thanks for all comments that have come. I will try to make some script, editing on my phone, to locate IP and user agent. It was just a while ago I was doing this kind of things.

Comment: This is from one of the pages. I just get Germany as IP location: [log](http://e-dog.info/t/63/doc/000_visitors.log.TMP.txt) // I should also add that I put this in the actual page, not in the one with random prefix. It is still called  very often.

Comment: As you can see from [here](https://check-host.net/ip-info?host=5.9.60.241), it looks like a server being used to scan, and as it is on an email [blacklist](http://sigs.interserver.net/ip?ip=5.9.60.241) it seems it is not only attacking your server

Comment: @jrtapsell Thx. I put a .htaccess deny in the directory. (I do not have full access to the GoDaddy server.) It seems to have stopped producing entries in my log at least. Really "criminal" behavior. (I am no expert on these things.)

Comment: Such is the internet.

Comment: I probably gave too low estimate of the amount of requests. I may have misread Google's report or it was not complete. Only one, less often hit page, where I linked to a log above, received 1000 hits/hour. Adding more often hit pages, would make the count hundreds of thousands per day. Adding to this the largest amount of requests for nonexisting pages would surely make the count any amount of millions per day. // I asked myself if the described requests with random prefix could be produced by my (GoDaddy) Apache when it was under high load. But that is just a wild guess.

Comment: Now I write a log file from, among others, my 404 file. But after denying IP 5.9.60.241, no more problems.

Answer (score 0):

The site was being scanned.

Redirecting calls to subdirectories of 5 random characters is a DDoS protection system for which GoDaddy (and Bluehost) have been criticized.

https://www.reddit.com/r/webhosting/comments/18v950/302_redirect_to_random_5_character_subdirectories/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307518/random-5-alpha-character-path-appended-to-requests

Comment: From your information, it is not a DDoS attack, not if it was from a single IP. And I corrected a misleading word in your answer.